# Trouble using Grep -v

Tags: scripting, grep

I'm currently trying to remove every line in a text file containing the line

"event/D:x:y:z:pmts1[122]:pmts2[122]:drift:Tot/D:S1:S2:S1Top:S1Bot:S2Top:S2Bot:logS2S1:pseudo_z:pseudo_z_s2".

I thought I would be able to this pretty easily using grep -v via the following:

```
grep -v  "event/D:x:y:z:pmts1[122]:pmts2[122]:drift:Tot/D:S1:S2:S1Top:S1Bot:S2Top:S2Bot:logS2S1:pseudo_z:pseudo_z_s2" data.txt >> NewData.txt
```

However, the command seems to just be stuck in an infinite loop or something, and no lines from data.txt are added to NewData.txt.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the pattern in single quotes if the first character is a double quote '"'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the metacharacters using `\`. Try:

```
grep -v "event\/D:x:y:z:pmts1\[122\]:pmts2\[122\]:drift:Tot\/D:S1:S2:S1Top:S1Bot:S2Top:S2Bot:logS2S1:pseudo_z:pseudo_z_s2" file.txt > newfile.txt
```

If you have `GNU sed`, you can write the changes directly to your file using the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i '/event\/D:x:y:z:pmts1\[122\]:pmts2\[122\]:drift:Tot\/D:S1:S2:S1Top:S1Bot:S2Top:S2Bot:logS2S1:pseudo_z:pseudo_z_s2/d' file.txt
```